# For-loop with function call issue

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm making a simple HTML/CSS/JavaScript text demo on codePen and I'm having issues with looping a function in the JavaScript. Here's what I have so far.

```
function loop() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        flicker();
    }
    var wait = (Math.random() * 4000);
    setTimeout(loop, wait);
}

function flicker() {
    $("#text").toggleClass('on');
}

loop();
```

If I take out the for loop, the text flickers. As soon as I add it back in, it freezes. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The effect I'm trying to get is 2 to 4 quick flickers, a longer pause, and then another set of flickers. Think neon signs. The codepen link is [here](http://codepen.io/batmiles/pen/EjxymL) if it helps.

Comment: Can you post codePen link?

Comment: http://codepen.io/batmiles/pen/EjxymL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are looping the "setTimeout" while "setTimeout" is still active. You sum up the timeouts which leads to an error.

What you are searching for is not a "for loop". Check this code (thanks Kaiido):

```js
var lastTime = 0;

function flickerPauses(){
  if(lastTime < 5){
    lastTime ++;
    return Math.random()*100;
  }else{
    lastTime = 0;
    return Math.random()*1200 + 100;
  }
}

function flicker() {
  $("#text").toggleClass('on');
  setTimeout(flicker, flickerPauses());
}

flicker();
```

```css
.on{
  display: none;
}
div{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"> Beer </div>
```

An early version which works but isn't as good as the first snippet:

```js
var inter;

function setInter(){
  inter = setInterval(flicker, Math.random() * 100);
}

function flicker() {
    $("#text").toggleClass('on');
    clearInterval(inter);
    setInter();
}

setInter();
```

```css
.on{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"> asdf </div>
```

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: But this will not have a random timeout between calls. It will "pulse" and not "flicker".

Comment: @JoeFrambach Sorry, I'll adapt this

Comment: @Kaiido Joe already pointed this out. I've adapted my code. I hope you love it this time ;)

Comment: That's better :-) But doesn't fit the new requirement in OP's question (I hate when they do that…)

Comment: @Kaiido :D :'( I'll adapt it <.<

Comment: @Kaiido Do you love it?

Comment: If you really want my point of view, It would be great to avoid this global `lastTime` but not so easy. Also, when returning the long timeout, you should consider adding a minimum of 100 ms, otherwise, `Math.random()*1300;`could return less than the last `Math.random()*100;`.

Comment: This works great guys. Thanks for the persistence. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Kaiido Check the solution now. Also I've added another "step".

Comment: if the sequence is 4 steps short and one long, then it doesn't work anymore. It'll be hard to do better than @JoeFrambach so maybe you should roll back to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply change `4` to `3`, it will work fine. Or any odd number really. I recommend `1`, and remove the loop.

Why?

Initial state -> off.
1 -> on.
2 -> off.
3 -> on.
4 -> off.

Every 1-4000 ms, you are doing absolutely nothing by keeping the state back to its starting place.

---

Edit: I now see what you are trying to accomplish. Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2nt33os/6/

It should do what you need.

```
$(function () {
    function longFlicker(callback) {
        $("#text").toggleClass('on');
        var wait = 1000+(Math.random() * 3000);
        setTimeout(shortFlickers, wait, 5);
    }
    function shortFlickers(remaining) {
        if (!remaining) return longFlicker();
        $("#text").toggleClass('on');
        var wait = (Math.random() * 300);
        setTimeout(shortFlickers, wait, remaining-1);
    }
    longFlicker();
});
```